# function undefined - but works in console

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have simple code like this:

```
function currentImageKey() {
  $('#akslide ul li.active').index();
}
```

If I simply call the function in console, I get "undefined".
Else, if I run the content of the function directly, like this

```
$('#akslide ul li.active').index();
```

It works and I get the index.

Why is it not working?
Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function doesn't have a `return` statement, so it returns `undefined`.

Add one.

```
function currentImageKey() {
  return $('#akslide ul li.active').index();
}
```

Comment: Works :) Thanks I'll validate the answer as soon as it allows me to